# After "killing" app it calls onStartCommand in my background service

Tags: android, service, background

In my MainActivity in `onCreate` I have this code which starts my background service:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
if(settings.getBoolean("backgroundRunning",true)&&isServiceRunning()==false){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

After killing app `onStartCommand()` is called again. `onDestroy()` is clear.

Comment: Do you return `START_STICKY` in your service' `onStartCommand`?

Comment: I added it but still the same problem

Comment: START_NOT_STICKY worked for me :D